# Automate transactions from hardware wallet: Proxy Contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, proxy-contracts, hardware-wallets

I have some scripts (web3.js) running that automatically send transactions for me. I'd like to secure the used funds with my hardware wallet (or really any "real" way), which is of course not immediately possible.
To solve my security concerns, I'm thinking of writing a kind of proxy contract to hold the funds. I'd then have that contract execute the transactions I need (calling it with my hot wallet), with a hardcoded withdraw() function to my HW address. Does that make sense? Is there maybe some "standard" way to solve my problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly possible without removing the added security that a hardware wallet provides. You really want to minimise the amount of exposure of your HW private key.

If you want the majority of your funds to remain in your hardware wallet. What you could do is convert the ETH sitting in your HW wallet to WETH which is an ERC20, you can then approve either your hot wallet or a smart contract to spend your required amount. Then during your automation, you can unwrap the WETH and use the Eth for your transactions.

This doesn't fully protect you because your hot wallet could still be compromised or your smart contract may have a security flaw. So be careful!